# Change page margin

Tags: margins

I have used `showframe` package and I noticed that my page contains allot of margin and possible two unwanted placeholders, one for page title and one for comments.
How can I remove those margins or change it's geometry?

```
\documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,10pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,
normalheadings,DIV=9,twoside=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage[nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
% twoside, openright
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\usepackage{showframe}

\title{A book title}   
\author{Temouri Sisaouri} 
\date{\today} 

\begin{document}

%=========================================
\begin{titlepage}
        \centering{
            {\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont 
            A book title}
        }\\

        \vspace{10mm}
        \centering{\Large{Temouri Sisaouri}}\\
        \vspace{\fill}
        \centering \large{2014}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see you are using the `geometry` package, did you look at its [documentation](http://ftp.oleane.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) file? It can do a lot of things for page layout.

Comment: I included `ignorehead` at the geometry definition but head remained there. Do `documentclass` interference with geometry?

Comment: With KOMA you can use \usepackage{typearea} and then \areaset[<binding offset>]{<width>}{<height>} to define your typearea. Then you have options for the margins. Use <number>headlines in the documentclass options (e.g. 1.25headlines), use \setlength{\marginparwidth}{<number>\marginparwidth} to set the width of marginal notes. The layout also depends on the headin(ex)clude, footin(ex)clude, mpin(ex)clude options in the documentclass. Fortunately this is well documented in the KOMA manual (at least the german one). For more control over type area, KOMA manual recommends the geometry package.

Comment: Well I am not sure what <binding offset> and <number> are. Can you provide an example with my current code?

Comment: That's not for a title. It is for a header e.g. to put document information there such as author/title/section name or page number etc. I'm actually not certain what the space for marginal notes is meant to be for. That is, since using such things seems like a fairly specific use-case, I'm not clear why that space is standard in most LaTeX layouts. However, just because you aren't using them don't assume that you want to use all of that space for the body of the document. That will typically crowd too much text onto the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,10pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,
normalheadings,twoside=false, 0.7headlines,headexclude]{scrbook} % DIV=9,

% \usepackage[nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
% twoside, openright
% \KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\usepackage{typearea}
\areaset[0mm]{11cm}{17cm} % selbst setzen

\usepackage{showframe}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0.7\marginparwidth}

\title{A book title}   
\author{Temouri Sisaouri} 
\date{\today} 

\begin{document}

%=========================================
\begin{titlepage}
        \centering{
            {\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont 
            A book title}
        }\\

        \vspace{10mm}
        \centering{\Large{Temouri Sisaouri}}\\
        \vspace{\fill}
        \centering \large{2014}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]